# OpenCV - Morphological Opening not idempotent

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, mathematical-morphology

EDIT: In the initial question the color map was reversed which caused some confusion, I changed the images and code to match so standard behavior.

Morphological opening and closing are idempotent operations (see [Univ. Auckland](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/courses/compsci773s1c/lectures/ImageProcessing-html/topic4.htm)):

> Opening is an idempotent operation: once an image has been opened,
> subsequent openings with the same structuring element have no further effect on that image:
>
> (f ∘ s) ∘ s = f ∘ s.

I have the following image:

[image: Black and white image with different shapes]

When trying to remove the skinny rectangles on the top right using OpenCV, I noticed that when I apply Opening iteratively with the same kernel, I get the desired result. To my understanding of how Opening/Closing works this should not be the case. Did I misunderstand anything or is there something wrong with the implementation in OpenCV?

Here is my example code and the results:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.rc('image', cmap='gray')

# load image
img = cv.imread("image.jpg", 0)

# apply binary thresholding to circumvent jpg compression
img = (img > 128).astype(np.uint8)

# adding a border around the image solves the issue
# img = cv.copyMakeBorder(img, 1, 1, 1, 1, cv.BORDER_CONSTANT)

kernel = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT,(20,5))
A = cv.morphologyEx(img, cv.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
B = cv.morphologyEx(A, cv.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
C = cv.morphologyEx(B, cv.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

f, ax = plt.subplots(1,3)
ax[0].imshow(A)
ax[0].set_title("A")
ax[1].imshow(B)
ax[1].set_title("B")
ax[2].imshow(C)
ax[2].set_title("C")

plt.show()
```

Here the result, notice the removed rectangles on the right border after each iteration:

[image: Rectangles removed iteratively]

Comment: That is indeed not right. It looks like OpenCV has an issue with the boundary expansion!

Comment: I think so too. I noticed, if you first apply a border around the image, e.g., using `img = cv.copyMakeBorder(img, 1, 1, 1, 1, cv.BORDER_CONSTANT)` it works. Guess I will open an issue on github.

Comment: please explore some more. first, morphology assumes *white on black* but you have *black on white*. opening should have **joined** your black rectangles, not removed them. something isn't right. -- `morphologyEx` uses BORDER_CONSTANT with 0 or something negative, so your rectangles on the border are actually just little bumps on a black surrounding. -- in any case, I agree that this is **not** how idempotency should look like. I noticed that your border rectangles _shrink_, which isn't how opening/closing is supposed to behave.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz That’s also right. f ∘ s <= f. But OP uses `cmap='gray_r'` just to confuse us all. ;)

Comment: Apologies for the confusion! This was part of an assignment where the image was to be specifically treated as binary image with the dark areas as 1 and bright areas as 0. As it was pointed out I reversed the color map to achieve the desired look. I will edit the images and code in the main question to avoid confusion.